# If and else inside a one-line python loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

Sorry if being so simple; as I searched elsewhere but nobody had pointed out to this specific problem. I'd like to learn python in a way that makes my code compact! So, to this end, I'm trying to make use of one-line (i.e., short) loops instead of multi-line loops, specifically, for loops. The problem arises when I try to use one-line if and else inside the one-line loops. It just doesn't seem to be working. Consider the following, for example:

```
numbers = ... # an arbitrary array of integer numbers

over_30 = [number if number > 30 for number in numbers]
```

This is problematic since `one-line if` does need `else` following it. Even though, when I add `else` to the above script (after `if`): `over_30 = [number if number > 30 else continue for number in numbers]`, it turns into just another pythonic error.

I know that the problem is actually with one-line if and else, because python needs to identify a value that should be assigned to the lefthand operator. But, is there a work-around for the specific use-case of this schema as above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are different syntaxes. The one you are looking for is:

```
over_30 = [number for number in numbers if number > 30]
```

This is a conditional list comprehension. The `else` clause is actually a non-conditional list comprehension, combined with a ternary expression:

```
over_30 = [number if number > 30 else 0 for number in numbers]
```

Here you are computing the ternary expression (`number if number > 30 else 0`) for each `number` in the `numbers` iterable.

Comment: Ugh! seems like this is where the ordering matters! Thank you Selcuk, I'll be marking your answer as the accepted one!

Comment: @inverted_index Don't think of it as the _ordering_ or you will be confused forever. They are actually different constructs. Read more about list comprehensions **and** ternary expressions.

Answer (score 2):

`continue` won't work since this is ternary expression, in which you need to return something.

`val1 if condition else val2`

You can try this way:

```
over_30 = [number for number in numbers if number > 30]
```